# Several errors during building shockwave ActiveX(Flash) in C++ Builder 2010

Tags: c++, flash, activex, c++builder

I have found one site where there is an instruction on how to build Shockwave ActiveX in C++ Builder but with errors. It comes from Chinese ... http://hi.baidu.com/luoshupeng/blog/item/c5bdaf446aed0988b3b7dc20.html

Does anyone know how to build ShockWave ActiveX in C++ builder 2010 as I had a transition from c++ builder 6 to c++ builder 2010 and much used to it, however it's possible to build it in c++ builder 6.

Errors are smth like these::::

Checking project dependencies...

Compiling ShockWave.cbproj (Debug configuration)

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::GetDispID(wchar_t *, unsigned long, long *)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::RemoteInvokeEx(long, unsigned long, unsigned long, tagDISPPARAMS *, tagVARIANT *, tagEXCEPINFO *, Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IServiceProvider *, unsigned int, unsigned int *, tagVARIANT *)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::DeleteMemberByName(wchar_t *, unsigned long)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::DeleteMemberByDispID(long)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::GetMemberProperties(long, unsigned long, unsigned long *)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::GetMemberName(long, wchar_t * *)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::GetNextDispID(unsigned long, long, long *)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall Shockwaveflashobjects_tlb::IDispatchEx::GetNameSpaceParent(IUnknown * *)' referenced from F:\个人重要资料(勿删)\ADMINISTRATOR\桌面\DEBUG\SHOCKWAVEFLASHOBJECTS_OCX.OBJ

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link

Failed

Elapsed time: 00:00:03.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reported issue over [here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=23482) that sounds similar to your problem. This comment below, in particular, sounds like a hint to solving your linking issues:

> The TLB declares the interface
>   IDispatchEx, but doesn't provide
>   implementations of virtual methods. As
>   methods are not declared pure, linker
>   is looking for them.
>
> Declaring methods inline simply fools
>   linker into thinking that no one is
>   referencing them. But if  one tries to
>   call such methods, linking failure
>   will occur.

Comment: You are right! After googling I have also found that eight methods should be inline and everything will be ok!! Thank you anyway ! i think it helps everyone who intend to use ShockWave ActiveX in c++ borland 2010 projects!!! I even have tried to delete C++ Builder  2010 but that thanks to you I am now working with it so far.  When i transited to c++ builder 2010, I thought, it's new and lots of things need to be done ! But it's cool ! Working great!

Comment: Still an issue with C++ Builder RAD Studio XE3. This workaround/solution works with it as well.

Comment: Nice to hear it! I'd like also to upgrade to X2 or X3.